# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:' pipe:: Invalid argument

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, pipe

When I run this command:

```
raspivid -n -vf -hf -t 0 -w 960 -h 540 -fps 25 -b 500000 -o - |
ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -metadata title="Streaming from raspberry pi camera" \
-f flv $RTMP_URL/$STREAM_KEY
```

it returns:

```
[NULL @ 0x3414410] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

How should I tweak my command line?

Comment: If you split up the command line you will see that this error is coming from ffmpeg. Obviously this command is malformed. Study the ffmpeg docs to find where it is going wrong. Lot's of hits for this error here and on the web.

Comment: The ffmpeg command looks alright, but given the error, it's presented here incorrectly and there's a stray space between a dash and an option somewhere.